HPE iLO | Delete SSL Certificate w. PowerShell
I have about a hundred servers that i need to do a repetitive process on.

Disable DHCPv4DomainName & DHCPv6DomainName
Set DNSName
Set DomainName

These are easily achievable by use HPEILOCMDLETS and 'Set-HPEiLOIPv4NetworkSetting' and 'Set-HPEiLOIPv6NetworkSetting' in that module. However, upon (well, actually before as well) performing the above another issue presents itself. The certificate ...

Delete and regenerate the (auto generated, self-signed) certificate.

And it's here i fall short of finding a way of doing this without actually using the GUI.
Therefor i am looking for a way of either deleting the SSL Certificate and let it reset and generate a new certificate with the "correct" CN or enable the setting to "Automatically manage SSL Certificate" which i think will generate a new certificate if there is a mismatch.
Anyone that have run into a similar problem and have a solution at hand?
Thanks in advance,
J

Managed to solve it.
    $Bdy = @"
    {"UserName": "<USERNAME>", "Password": "<PASSWORD>"}
    "@
    $LoginResp = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri "https://<HPEILO>/redfish/v1/SessionService/Sessions/" -ContentType 'application/json' -Body $Bdy -SkipCertificateCheck
    $XAuthToken = $($LoginResp.Headers.'X-Auth-Token')
    $resp = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Delete -Uri "https://<HPEILO>/redfish/v1/Managers/1/SecurityService/httpscert/" -ContentType 'application/json' -Headers @{"X-Auth-Token" = $XAuthToken} -SkipCertificateCheck```

